# Fan accelerates increasingly when idle/at a stop

Tags: overheating, fan

I have a 2004 Jeep Grand Cherokee. While sitting in idle/at a stop, temperature increases a little to just above 210 and the fan is increasingly loud - sounds like it's going to burst out. It also makes a clicking noise as the speed increases. After shutting off the motor and restarting it seems to be fine until it heats up again while sitting.

What could be causing this?

Comment: Is there a reason you _wouldn't_ expect the fans to come on when the engine heats up?  They are trying to cool off the engine, right?

Comment: @JPhi1618 I think his concern is the loud noise and clicking noise.

Comment: @rana You may be right - I read the clicking noise as the high-speed relay turning on (does it click more than once?), and of course the higher speed would be louder.  I guess we just need more details.

Comment: Probably the root cause of the fan noise and clicking is the engine is running too hot.

Comment: This model has a viscous fan clutch, right? The fan clutches on this particular era of Jeep/Dodge are very noisy when they engage. Please confirm that this isn't a sudden occurrence

Comment: This just started happening. It's like a loud roaring noise, almost as if it's about to blow. And before it accelerates excessively there are about three clicking noises. The motor has been running around it's normal temp.

Comment: Maybe it just sounds like excessive speed because it's noisier that it used to be?  Is it possible that the fan cracked or maybe the fan motor bearings are going out?

Comment: The cooling fan is electric. Jump battery voltage to the fan, is it still noisy? Is there debris in the fan? With the fan motor disconnected is there play in the shaft?

Answer (score 1):

We had a similar problem on our 09 Chevy HHR, it would heat up at long lights and in bad traffic. Sometimes the fan would go into a hi speed mode that was quite loud.

I would suggest going to a Jiffy Lube or similar type of place to have the cooling system flushed. That solved our problem, now it runs below 200 all the time. You definitly don't want to overheat the engine, that could cause a warped cyl. head or worse, and be very expensive. If the flush doesn't work, you might try replacing the thermostat. The water pump is also suspect, but try the cheaper fixes first. Good luck.